# Remove Mega Slider (MD Slider)

Tags: drupal-7

I have a `Drupal 7.36` site up and running and it has the `Mega Slider` (listed as `MD Slider`) component installed.  I want to remove this component so I started by removing the slide I had created with it, I then went to the Modules area and wanted to disable it but I am not able to.  I think it is because there are some items that are required to use MD Slider.  The items that are required by `MD Slider` are custom items under the `Structure | Content Types` menu.  When I go to those items, I am not able to find the dependency so I can remove it.

Any suggestions on a way to remove `MD Slider`?

Comment: Are there any modules you installed which depends upon MD Slider?

Answer (score 0):

To remove an MD Slider completely, you need to follow several steps:

1. Access the Slider by going to 'Structure' > 'MD Sliders'.
2. Click on the 'Configure' link next to the Slider you want to delete.
3. At the bottom, there is the 'Delete' button. By clicking it you will be redirected to the delete confirmation page.
4. Click on 'Delete' to remove the slider completely.

**Note.** MD Slider has a small bug with i18n sites, as it compares the 'op' value of the submitted form with the t('') value of the submit button. Thus, to be able to delete it you need to access the administrative pages in English.

Good luck!